# Javascript button to insert a big black dot (•) into a html textarea

Tags: javascript, utf-8, textarea, special-characters, text-editor

I have a `textarea` in a `html form` and I would like to have a button to add a big black dot character (•) (is this called a bullet?) into this `textarea`. is it possible in `javascript`?

Also it needs to be a `UTF8` character.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just access the element and append it to the value.

```
<input
     type="button" 
     onclick="document.getElementById('myTextArea').value += '•'" 
     value="Add •">
```

See [a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vtbMS/).

For the sake of keeping things simple, I haven't written [unobtrusive JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). For a production system you should.

> Also it needs to be a UTF8 character.

Browsers generally submit forms using the encoding they received the page in. Serve your page as UTF-8 if you want UTF-8 data submitted back.

Comment: @David — The `innerHTML` property will set the *default* value, `value` will set the *current* value. It is the current value that we care about. Don't confuse the value *property* with the *attribute* of the same name.

Comment: Note the [DOM spec for textareas](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-24874179) which defines the value property: *Represents the current contents of the corresponding form control, in an interactive user agent. Changing this attribute changes the contents of the form control*

Answer (score 5):

you can use html entity as `&bull;`